# AngularJS: "Bad Argument" when using angular.bootstrap

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to run two AngularJS apps on the same page, angucomplete and pickadate (https://github.com/restorando/angular-pickadate) but it's not working.

Here is my HTML

```
<div id="Lookup">
            <div ng-controller="LookupController">

                <div class="row" id="Origin">

                    <div class="small-12 large-10 large-centered columns">

                        <label for="From">From:</label>

                        <div angucomplete-alt id="OriginSearch"
                             placeholder="Enter a placename"
                             pause="300"
                             selected-object="selectedOrigin"
                             remote-url="~/en/trip-details/LocationList?partialLocationName="
                             title-field="Name"
                             minlength="3"
                             match-class="highlight"
                             field-required="true" />
                    </div>
                    <pre ng-bind="position|json" />
                </div>
            </div>
                </div>

                <div id="datetimepicker">
                <div ng-controller="DateTimePickerController">

                    <section id="TravellingOn">
                        <div style="width: 400px; float: left; margin-right: 50px;">
                            <div pickadate ng-model="TravellingOn" min-date="minDate" max-date="maxDate" week-starts-on="0"></div>
                    </section>

                </div>
                </div>
                </div>
```

and my Javascript...

```
//Dropdowns

var dropdowns = angular.module('dropdowns', ["angucomplete-alt"]);

dropdowns.controller('LookupController', ['$scope', '$http',
function LookupController($scope, $http) {
    $scope.remoteUrlRequestFn = function (str) {
        return { q: str };
    };

}
]);



//Date / Time Picker

angular.module('DateTimePicker', ['pickadate'])
       .controller('DateTimePickerController', function ($scope) {

           var todayNow = moment().format("YYYY-MM-DD");
           var twoWeekView = moment().add(13, 'days').format("YYYY-MM-DD");

           $scope.date = todayNow;
           $scope.minDate = todayNow;
           $scope.maxDate = twoWeekView;

           });


angular.element(document).ready(function () {
    angular.bootstrap(document.getElementById('Lookup'), ['dropdowns']);
    angular.bootstrap(document.getElementById('datetimepicker'), ['DateTimePicker']);

});
```

When I bootstrap them together I get the following...

Argument 'DateTimePickerController' is not a function, got undefined

The can both exist happily on their own if only one is bootstrapped but both together and it throws the above error. Bit lost on this one, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Why can't you create a new module which depends on the two modules you have created and bootstrap that one.

Comment: Fix your HTML with proper closing tags first